# Appending one xml document to another

Tags: xml, groovy

Input xml is

```
<FormXML>
  <Info1>
    <Element11/>
    <Element22/>
    <Element33/>
  </Info1>
  <Info2>
    <Element14/>
    <Element25/>
    <Element36/>
  </Info2>
  <Info3>
    <Element17/>
    <Element28/>
    <Element39/>
  </Info3>
</FormXML>
```

Then parsing it like this:

```
def formXML = new XmlSlurper().parseText(requestXML)
def info = """<Info></Info>"""
formXML.children().each {
  if(it.name()=="Info1" || it.name()=="Info3")
  {
   info.append(XmlUtil.serialize(it))
  }
}
```

Getting error for `append()`. I tried

```
info.append(it)
info.add(it)
```

But getting error for both the methods.
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
info.appendNode(it)
```

did the trick.